# Highlight on click in vue, javascript, html and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vue.js

I am new with html, javascript and css. I believe that what I'm working with is Vue, which I'm completely new to. I am trying to make my page highlightable when I click on it. Currently, it only highlights when I hover, however I am not able to identify the id for the table from the html portion of the code.

Looked at multiple solutions online, however they all direct towards a premade table, however mine is a table that has multiple pages.

```html
<template>
 <div>
  <h1>Questions</h1>
  <el-row  type="flex" justify="end"> 
   <a-button type="primary" @click="createNewQuestion()">New Question</a-button>

   <div  v-if="this.categoryDetail !== null">&emsp;</div> 
   <a-button-group>
     <a-button v-if="this.categoryDetail !== null" type="primary" @click="addQuestion()">Add Question</a-button> 
     <a-button v-if="this.categoryDetail !== null" :disabled="!hasSelected" type="danger" @click="removeQuestion()">Remove Question</a-button>
   </a-button-group>
  </el-row>
  <hr>
  <a-table :dataSource="tdata" :columns="columns"
    :customRow="customRow"
    @change="onChange" rowKey="id" :loading="loading">
   <div
    slot="filterDropdown"
    slot-scope="{ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters, column }"
    class="custom-filter-dropdown"
   >
    <a-input
     v-ant-ref="c => searchInput = c"
     :placeholder="`Search ${column.dataIndex}`"
     :value="selectedKeys[0]"
     @change="e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])"
     @pressEnter="() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)"
     style="width: 188px; margin-bottom: 8px; display: block;"
    />
    <a-button
     type="primary"
     @click="() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)"
     icon="search"
     size="small"
     style="width: 90px; margin-right: 8px"
    >Search</a-button>
    <a-button @click="() => handleReset(clearFilters)" size="small" style="width: 90px">Reset</a-button>
   </div>
   <a-icon
    slot="filterIcon"
    slot-scope="filtered"
    type="search"
    :style="{ color: filtered ? '#108ee9' : undefined }"
   />
   <template slot="customRender" slot-scope="text">
    <span v-if="searchText">
     <template
      v-for="(fragment, i) in text.toString().split(new RegExp(`(?<=${searchText})|(?=${searchText})`, 'i'))"
     >
      <mark
       v-if="fragment.toLowerCase() === searchText.toLowerCase()"
       :key="i"
       class="highlight"
      >{{fragment}}</mark>
      <template v-else>{{fragment}}</template>
</template>
</span>
<template v-else>{{text}}</template>
</template>
<template slot="viewButton" slot-scope="text,record">
    <a-button type="primary" @click="viewClicked(record)">View</a-button>
     
   </template>
</a-table>

<el-dialog title="Question Details" :visible.sync="dialogDetailVisible" width="50%" :close-on-click-modal="false" append-to-body @close='closeQuestionDetailDialog'>

  <QuestionDetail @afterSubmitChanges="afterSubmitDetail" :recordData="record_data" ref="question_detail"></QuestionDetail>
</el-dialog>

<el-dialog top="5vh" title="Select Questions" :visible.sync="dialogSelectVisible" width="50%" :close-on-click-modal="false" append-to-body @close='closeQuestionSelectDialog'>

  <SelectQuestion @onCloseDialog="closeSelectDialog" ref="question_select"></SelectQuestion>
</el-dialog>

<el-dialog title="New Question" :visible.sync="dialogNewVisible" width="50%" :close-on-click-modal="false" append-to-body @close='afterCloseNewDialog'>

  <NewQuestion @onCloseDialog="closeNewDialog" ref="question_new" :categoryDetail="categoryDetail"></NewQuestion>
</el-dialog>

</div>
</template>
```

Most of the solutions also use jquery while I'm working with javascript.

Please let me know if more detailed code is required. I'm not sure what to put here.

Comment: That is not HTML. Please tag accurately.

Comment: is it not? I got it from the portion of my code which starts with <template> <div> <h1> etc.

Comment: What is an `a-table`?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to figure out. Is it better if i just show what I think is the html portion of the code?

Comment: Yes, show more HTML

Comment: I added the portion of what I presume is the entire chunk of html. the next portion is the script which I can kinda work with since I've a bit of knowledge with java. Thanks

Comment: This looks like you are using some kind of framework like Django which parses the HTML file and transforms these `a-table` etc tags into valid HTML. Can you run your page in your browser, right click, press `View page source` and then paste the result into your question. That would allow us to see what HTML it is turning into.

Comment: Firstly, `<template>` tag is not interpreted by HTML rendering engine; you basically need some kind of clientside library to make sense of it and do something with it. Seeing `v-if` in there, I'm tempted to say you're using Vue.js, but I am not that familiar with it. Given that you're using a framework (and custom JavaScript) to process your click events, it's really hard to say what you're doing with just what you posted. Regarding the table id - it doesn't have one, so no wonder you can't find it. You could add it if you wanted to, but if using Vue, you would typically not need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am not able to paste the result in my question as it just comes out as: "We're sorry but dss-admin doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue." I also tried to upload an image but it doesnt work. Maybe this link might work: https://imgur.com/DyLeNOS

Comment: Thanks Amadan, I just saw my visual studio and the tabs end with .vue. No wonder I couldn't understand a single thing I was working with.